# Form with multiple steps (wizard style) in Flutter - Best approach

Tags: forms, flutter, dart

I need to prepare a screen to create a new record for a table with several fields. Some fields are conditional on previous fields. My initial attempt includes a TabController/TabBarView/Tabs set where every tab is a part of the form.

My two problems there are:

- I cannot seem to be able to hide the "tab" (icon/text) itself in a TabBarView ( I want to use a button for "Next Step")
- Even if I live with that, if I build a widget for each tab, I'd need a GlobalKey for every Form (one for each tab) as they cannot be shared.

Is there another way to do this, with another widget or approach so as to have a Form divided in several steps/screens and then submit the whole data as a whole?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the Stepper Widget. it can enable you from making vertical or horizontal wizard from multiple steps.

```
Stepper({
  Key key,
  @required this.steps,
  this.physics,
  this.type = StepperType.vertical,
  this.currentStep = 0,
  this.onStepTapped,
  this.onStepContinue,
  this.onStepCancel,
  this.controlsBuilder,
})
```

You can follow this example by **Paul Halliday**
https://developer.school/flutter-how-to-use-the-stepper-widget/

Comment: This looks exactly like the solution i need. Thanks I'll try asap!

Comment: @GregoryRay sorry I've left Flutter for a while, and for that project specifically I went for my solution below, but yours was very useful for other matters, so yeah, definitely accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a better way to handle this. I'll throw away the Tabs altogether (though I think it's possible to "embed" this logic in tabs) as the Next/Previous buttons maybe just enough. I keep a single form (key) this way and it seems to work perfectly at the save moment.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

void main() => runApp(MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Sandbox',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sandbox'),
      ),
      body: Container(
         padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
         color: Colors.white,
         child: FormWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class FormWidget extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _FormWidgetState createState() => _FormWidgetState();
}

class _FormWidgetState extends State<FormWidget> {


  int _stepNumber = 1;

  final ctl_name = TextEditingController();
  final ctl_age = TextEditingController();
  final ctl_address = TextEditingController();
  final ctl_city = TextEditingController();

  void saveData(BuildContext context) {

    _formKey.currentState.save();

    print(ctl_name.text);
    print(ctl_age.text);
    print(ctl_address.text);
    print(ctl_city.text);

  }

  void nextPage(BuildContext context) {

    setState(() {
      if (_stepNumber == 1)
        _stepNumber = 2;
      else
        _stepNumber = 1;
    });
  }


  Column formOneBuilder(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)),
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Text("STEP 1")
          ),
        ),
        TextFormField(
          controller: ctl_name,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Step 1 Name'
          ),
        ),
        TextFormField(
          controller: ctl_age,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Step 2 Age'
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text('Next'),
                  onPressed: () {nextPage(context);} ,
                ),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8)),
                FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text('Save'),
                  onPressed: () {saveData(context);} ,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }


  Column formTwoBuilder(BuildContext context) {

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.red)),
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Text("STEP 2"),
          ),
        ),
        TextFormField(
          controller: ctl_address,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Step 2 Address'
          ),
        ),
        TextFormField(
          controller: ctl_city,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Step 2 City'
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text('Previous'),
                  onPressed: () {nextPage(context);} ,
                ),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8)),
                FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text('Save'),
                  onPressed: () {saveData(context);} ,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    switch (_stepNumber) {
      case 1:
          return Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child:
                this.formOneBuilder(context),
          );
          break;

      case 2:
        return Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child:
                this.formTwoBuilder(context),
        );
        break;
    }

  }

  void dispose() {

    ctl_address.dispose();
    ctl_age.dispose();
    ctl_city.dispose();
    ctl_name.dispose();

    super.dispose();

  }


}
```